# Cellular towers in rectangular grid

Tags: antenna-array, cellular

Not that far from where I live there are 6 towers that appear to be for cellular purposes in a perfect grid. You can see them in the picture I took from google maps. In the center of the road are lights, but on either side you can see 3 poles. Is there something special going on here, or are these just 6 towers that have been placed in a grid for convenience? They are far to far apart for any phased-array type stuff, unless they are operating at a few tens of MHz. [image]

Comment: Those look too short to be cellular towers. They're barely any taller than the street lights...

Comment: Speed trap alarm bells ringing LOL.

Comment: @brhans this is a highway, so these lights are quite tall. I have seen them in person and they are very similar in size and appearance from what I know are cell towers. (if you consider the fact that they are well above the tree canopy, and these are big oak trees...)

Comment: Aren't those a bit close together to be cell towers?

Comment: Google Street View URL?